# jQuery how to auto adjust the number list when 1 of the list is removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to automatically adjust the number list that was created using `.append()`. Example, if there are 4 items added on the list which will numbered from 2-4 respectively and if I removed item number 3, the item number 4 will automatically be number 3 and if I add a new item, it will be the last on the list. Here's my code below.

```js
$('#display').click(function() {
  $('#show').show();
});
var c = 1;
$('#append').click(function() {
  var cnt = $('.cnt').val();
  for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    c++;
    $('#inputs').append("<div id='inputs' name='" + c + "'>" + c + ".)<button id='remove' name='" + c + "'>X</button></div>");
  }
});
$(document).on('click', '#inputs #remove', function() {
  var nm = $(this).attr('name');
  $('div[name="' + nm + '"]').remove();
  c--;
});
```

```css
#show {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/master/src/jquery.mask.js"></script>
<button id='display'>Display</button>
<div id='show'>
  <br>
  <input type='text' class='cnt' value='1' placeholder="num of append" />
  <button id='append'>+</button>
  <br>
  <div id='inputs'>
    1.)
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2e0qyrq3/5/) of the code.

Comment: theres just so much code... it'll take someone a good 10 minutes at least just to figure out whats going on

Comment: by the way you're appending new inputs that have the x button. The x button has a static `id='button'` and a div `id='inputs'` this means you append 5 times, you will have 10 elements with duplicate ids, this is not valid

Comment: I think because of  `var c = 1;` the 'c' value will always 1 when doing `c++`.

Comment: Meh. Most answers are similar. http://jsfiddle.net/2e0qyrq3/8/ You should probably use labels for your well... labels. Otherwise I think others corrected issues with your IDs, so I'll remove my answer. Reorganize your code though, it's quite messy.

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac This guy nirmal just copied my function without any changes, this is rude!!!!

Comment: @SamBattat How come he copied your function where in fact he's the one who post the answer first?

Comment: `resetiInputsCount` before I added comments. Dude look the time mine was posted first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is your answer

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nil4you/2e0qyrq3/9/)

```js
$('#display').click(function() {
  $('#show').show();
});
var c = 1;
$('#append').click(function() {
  var cnt = $('.cnt').val();
  for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    c++;
    $('#inputs').append("<div class='inputs' name='" + c + "'><span class='number'>" +c + "</span>.)<button class='remove' name='" + c + "'>X</button></div>");
  }
});
$(document).on('click', '#inputs .remove', function() {
  var nm = $(this).attr('name');
  $('div[name="' + nm + '"]').remove();
  c--;
resetCount();
});
function resetCount(){
    $('#inputs div.inputs').each(function(i){
        $('.number', $(this)).text(i+2);
        $('input', $(this)).attr('name', i+2);
    });
}
```

```css
#remain,
#total {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
input:focus {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
input {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
#show {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='display'>Display</button>
<div id='show'>
  <br>
  <input type='text' class='cnt' value='1' placeholder="num of append" />
  <button id='append'>+</button>
  <br>
  <div id='inputs'>
    1.)
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you just copy my function or just happened that we wrote the same function character for character????!!!!

Comment: will reset entire list on each row remove - terrible answer especially if the rows will contain some user generated values.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using the same ID for different elements

Also the way you could do this is by creating a function that resets the elements counting after each add/delete event

When creating and appending elements in jQuery its better to use this syntax:

```
$('<ELEMENT TAG/>',{
  ATTRIBUTE: VALUE
});
```

When looping through elements in jQuery its better to use `$.each`

```
$('#append').on('click', function(){
    $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'inputs',
        html: '<span class="count"></span><input type="text" class="time" name="0" value="00:00:00"/><button>X</button>'
    }).appendTo('#inputs');
    resetInputsCount();
});

$('#inputs').on('click', '.inputs button', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().remove();
    resetInputsCount();
});

//The function that resets the count span text and the name value based on the current count of elements
function resetInputsCount(){
    //looping through elements
    $('#inputs div.inputs').each(function(i){
        //caching the current element in a var named $this
        var $this = $(this);
        //changing the count span text to i+2 the 2 is added because the index starts at 0 and there is already one element 1.)
        $('.count', this).text((i+2) + '.) ');
        //change the value of the input name
        $('input', $this).attr('name', i+2);
    });
}
```

[**Demo on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2e0qyrq3/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I know theres an answer already but since I did the work I might as well post it.

[Here's the fiddle for the example](http://jsfiddle.net/qgca08e0/)

here's the code:

Html

```
<div id='button'>
 <span>Add</span>
</div>
<div id='content'></div>
```

CSS

```
#button span {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    background: #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#button {
    margin: 5px 0;
}
.delete {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 5px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var index = 1;
    $('#button').on('click', function() {
        var add = '<div class="new"><span class="number">' + index + '</span><input type="text"/><span class="delete">x</span></div>';
        $('#content').append(add);
        index++;
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
        index--;
        $(this).parent().remove();
        var index2 = 1;
        var newelement = $('.new');
        $(newelement).each(function() {
            $(this).find('.number').text(index2);
            index2++;
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Using your html structure and adding some input fields (to be sure we maintain values)

Here is my approach: 
(Also fixed duplicate id and names you have)

```js
$('#display').click(function() {
  $('#show').show();
});
var c = 1;
var inputs = [];


$('#append').click(function() {
  var cnt = $('.cnt').val();
  for (var i=0; i<cnt; i++) {
    c++;
    $div = $("<div id='input"+c+"' />").data('index', c);
    $span = $("<span />").text(c+".)");
    $button = $("<button class='input_remove' />").text("X");
    $input =  $("<input type='text' class='small' />").attr("name","input"+c);
    $div.append($div).append($span).append($input).append($button);
    $('#inputs').append($div);
  }
});


$(document).on('click', '.input_remove', function() {
  index = $(this).parent().data('index');
  $("#inputs").find('#input'+index).remove();
  c = 1;
  $("#inputs").find('div').each(function(index,ele){
    c++;
    $(ele).attr('id',"input"+c).data('index',c)
          .find("span").text(c+".)").end()
          .find("input").attr("name","input"+c);
  });
});
```

```css
#show {
  display: none;
}
.small { width:100px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/master/src/jquery.mask.js"></script>
<button id='display'>Display</button>
<div id='show'>
  <br>
  <input type='text' class='cnt' value='1' placeholder="num of append" />
  <button id='append'>+</button>
  <br>
  <div id='inputs'>
    1.)
  </div>
</div>
```